# How to schedule/organize python modules in virtualenv?

Tags: python, cron, virtualenv, airflow, luigi

I developed a few python modules and run them in a virtualenv.
I would like to schedule such tasks (and add some dependencies)
to run at specific times.

For example something like this:
I've got some python modules like

```
moduleA.py, moduleB.py, moduleC.py, moduleD.py
```

and they will be organized like:

```
Project A
--------- moduleA.py
--------- moduleB.py
--------- moduleC.py

Project B
--------- moduleB.py
--------- moduleD.py
```

So now I want Project A to run in the virtualenv "projectA".
So it should that enviroment with `source /virtualenv/projectA/bin/active`.
Ok. That could be done by a Shell - Script.
But then it should start moduleA.py and when that's finished start with moduleB.py and so on. Finally the enviroment can be deactivated.

This procedure should be repeated to different times and projects.
I don't know which method would be a good choice.
I read about luigi, airflow or even thought about crontab.
I would like get some hints.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The right choice depends on your exact use case. Cron, airflow and luigi, all can be used for this. If you only have 2 projects and you don't foresee changing them often, then a simple bash script run by cron job should be sufficient.
If you need error handling, email on failure, UI etc. then either luigi or airflow will be fine.